# How can i set selected item property from the list using code behind?

Tags: list, list-item

```
div id="Div1" class="myTeams">
     <div class="listTitle">My Teams</div>
    <div id="myTeams">
        <select id="myGroupList" name="myGroupList" onchange="reloadMYUser('myIntContacts');" size="10" />
<option value="abc_group"  selected >abc</option>
<option value="def_group" >def</option>
<option value="ghi_group" >ghi</option>
<option value="jkl_group" >jki</option>
 </select>

    </div>
```

i would like to search any group from the above list if it finds my group it should apply selected property for that list item. how can i do this from the codebehind?

Comment: To access the control from server side, it should have `runat="server"` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

```
ListItem listItem = myGroupList.Items.FindByValue("def_group");

if (listItem != null)
{
    listItem.Selected = true;
};
```

You can modify it to pass a variable in first line, in place of `"def_group"`.

Comment: thanks for your answer....unfortunately MyTeams is accessible from codebehind but i am unable to access myGroupList.